# How to make a non responsive menu

Tags: html, css

How can I make a non-responsive menu. For example, I have a menu with 5 li's displayed inline but on certain resolution they start to jump under each other. How can I stop them to do that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Need to see your code to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a fixed width on the parent container of your menu.

https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_recci/vjdsv2tb/1/

```
<ul class="main-menu">
   <li>I am a menu item</li>
   <li>I am a menu item</li>
   <li>I am a menu item</li>
   <li>I am a menu item</li>
   <li>I am a menu item</li>
</ul>

.main-menu {
   width: 900px;
}

.main-menu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I Think you can simply set a width at the ul
check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qjm1h2L5/1/

```
ul{
   width:600px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When working with inline elements, the `white-space` property allows you to disable line wrapping. It's one of the more oddly-named properties in CSS.

```
ul { white-space: nowrap; }
li { display: inline; }
```

Comment: It indeed does. Keep in mind it might cause problems because the list items stay inline, they might start poking outside the parent (container).